# How to make text file (or other documents') parser?

Tags: parsing, text, nlp, tokenize

I have following task to do: to fill spell check dictionary (simple txt file) I need parser
which should: - parse within text file (or another type of document), extract
each word and then create text file with simple list of words like this:
adfadf
adfasdfa
adfasfdasdf
adsfadf
...
etc
What scripting language and library you would suggest? If possible, please, give example of code (especially for extracting each word). Thanks!

Comment: you should search for something called tokenizer, which divides your sequence of words into tokens which can be passed to the dictionary. There are a lot o open source projects online. Here you may find a sort of algorithm in java: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/72regular/Tokenizer.java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not a parser, but just a tokenizer. This can be done in any language with a bunch of regular expressions, but I do recommend Python with [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/):

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> word_tokenize('Hello, world!')
['Hello', ',', 'world', '!']
```

Generally, just about any [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) toolkit will include a tokenizer, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel; tokenizing isn't hard, but it involves writing a lot of heuristics to handle all the exceptions such as abbreviations, acronyms, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I'll digg in that way

Comment: @user939536: don't forget to click the checkmark next to this answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: all right, it really helped! my aquaintants are creating this script, thanks!